# Change the user role on nth number of orders after successful order placement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I previously implemented a solution to change the user role on registration, but seem to be missing something this time around.

Does anyone out there have a solution for this that still works or be able to point me in the right direction as to what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Does is what I have tried so far.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'change_user_role_on_order_success');

function change_user_role_on_order_success($order_id ) {
 // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );
    // Count number of orders
    $count = count( $customer_orders );

     // return "true" when customer has already one order
    if ( $count >= 1 ) {
        $user = new WP_User( $order->get_user_id() );

        // our new role name
        $role = 'editor';

        //set the new role to our customer
           $user->set_role($role);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please elaborate the problem you ran into and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use the hook `woocommerce_order_status_completed` instead. It should fire as soon as your customer really completed the order and removes the need for you to check for the status.

```
function change_user_role_on_order_status_completed( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $user_id = $order->user_id;

    $total_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
    ) );

    if ( $total_orders > 1 ) {
        $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

        // Set role editor
        $user->set_role( 'editor' );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_user_role_on_order_status_completed', 10, 1 );
```